# Execute process - read output/error stream together in chronological order

Tags: java

I'm executing a different Process using the `java.lang.Process` class and want to get the whole output (stdout and stderr) in a single string. The output should be in chronological order (i.e., the same order I would see it on a terminal). How can I do that? I've only found ways to read them as separate streams - which makes it hard to correlate later on.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the System output and error stream to the same stream should do the trick:

```
    var stream = new PrintStream(...);
    System.setErr(stream);
    System.setOut(stream);
```

If you want to additionally capture the output of a process, you started, you could use The `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()` method to copy the processes stdout and stderr to the JVM‘s stdout and stderr

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(script.sh).inheritIO();
```

Comment: The idea is good, but this code does not help on executing another process...

Comment: Right. The OP didn‘t say explicitely, that he wants to capture stdout and stderr from another system process, but I guess that does make sense

Comment: I added an example of how you could capture the stdout and stderr of the spawned process. It isn‘t pretty and probably not what you want, but could work.